# App starts with the wrong page suddenly

Tags: android

Hy!

I just added a new Class, a new Activitity in the Manifest and add the startActivityforResult in the Main Class (start Class). Suddenly the apps starts with the wrong Activity

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="android.skiptvad"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".Main"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Login"/>
        <activity android:name=".NewAccount"/>
        <activity android:name=".Channellist"/>
        <activity android:name=".MainScreen"/>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />

</manifest>
```

Main Class:

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.main);
       startActivityForResult(new Intent(Main.this, Login.class), 1);
       startActivityForResult(new Intent(Main.this, Channellist.class), 1);
       startActivityForResult(new Intent(Main.this, MainScreen.class), 1);
       //finish();
    }
}
```

The app starts with the main screen instead of the login.

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make any sense to call `startActivityForResult` multiple times in a row.  Instead, you should just start the `Login` activity. When that activity finished, [onActivityResult][1] will be called. You can then start the next activity.

The calls to `startActivityForResult` are asynchronous.  This means that currently when you call it for Login, it does not wait for that activity to complete and it immediately calls the next one, and then `MainScreen`.  Since `MainScreen` is last, it wins.

[1]: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int, int, android.content.Intent)

Answer (score 1):

You are calling 3 new activities, in order `login`, `channellist` and `mainscreen`. I think you mean to start just the login, and from there start the main?

I don't see any need to call 3x `startActivityForResult` in the oncreate?